# It will not happen overnight, anything worth obtaining or doing rarely does

Tags: grammar

I didn't understand the uses of this “does”  here in the sentence

Comment: It's a reduced form of *...rarely does **happen overnight***, where the highlighted element is "deleted" because it's a ***predictable*** repetition in a parallel construction. Obviously the auxiliary verb *(**does**)* is optional in the "full" form, but it needs to be there if we're going to delete the other words.

Comment: And let's replace the comma with an em bar or semicolon.

Comment: It’s worth noting too that this is an idiomatic pattern of sentence construction in English. Other examples: “That chair will cost you a packet - antique furniture of that quality often does.”  “The pug died young of a congenital defect - dogs of this breed often do.”